# Dreamweaver CS5.5 color theme for Zend Studio or NetBeans 7.1?

Tags: netbeans, dreamweaver, zend-studio, color-scheme

Looking for classic color theme of DW CS5.5 to put on Zend Studio or at least on NetBeans. Does anybody know any places to find because my search didn't bring any result.

UPD: I've earned the "Tumbleweed" badge for this question. Why? Nobody answered it, nobody gave the thumbs up for it. Strange.